# PM2 --max-memory-restart: EADDRINUSE: address already in use

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a `node.js` application running on several systems behind a nginx loadbalancer. During day and peak hours, these nodes start to consume more memory and cpu, and they gracefully restart when they reach a threshold of 640MB memory. The restarts are controlled with a `PM2` json script and `max-memory-restart`.

Problem now is that sometimes, not always, after the restart, the new process cannot be launched because the port is still in use. It is happening randomly on all nodes.

The error:

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8888
>       at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1255:14)
>       at listenInCluster (net.js:1303:12)
>       at Server.listen (net.js:1391:7)
>       ...

The server.json script:

```
{
  "name"   : "server.json",
  "script" : "server.js",
  "max_memory_restart" : "640M",
  "log_date_format" : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z"
}
```

What can be wrong? Note: I cannot start the server.json in cluster mode because I only have one cpu per system.

Comment: Sounds like the port `8888` is still in use and therefore the new process could not bind to it. I'm not sure how your application works so can't tell exactly. My theory is the process is still shutting down but before it could release port `8888` another copy of it tried to bind to it.

Comment: Consider tuning your restart script, if it fails with that error, find what process is holding the port.

Comment: Would --restart-delay parameter help?